# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to user without a default; we can't do that

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am building a custom User class in django to use in creating a signup application and I keep on getting the error above every time I try to makemigrations.As far as I can see, my code is per django documentation here.I also have AUTH_USER_MODEL correctly placed in my settings configurations. Here's my models.py

```
# from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, default='email')
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False, default='first_name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False, default='last_name')
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+91 ...'")
    phone_no = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17,blank=False, default='phone_number')
    # email_validator = EmailValidator(message='Invalid email
    # address',code=None,whitelist=None)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    # Email & Password are required by default
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name():
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        # does user have a specific permission
        return True

    def has_module_pers(self, app_label):
        # does user have permissions to view the app 'app_label'
        return True

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.is_admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.is_active

# Create your models here.""
```

Comment: The problem come from this `create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):` you can't have a null password when create

Comment: I have removed None from create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields): but still same issue

Comment: Can you add your user model in the question too ?

Comment: It is here only please scroll down

Comment: i see, next time please separate each code format per section so it's easier to notice, your question maybe related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35120058/11225821) if you can try to delete other user that existed in your database and set the password back to the original of `create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields)`

Comment: Thanks That issue is resolved

Comment: ```
File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\model_meta.py", line 96, in _get_forward_relationships                                                        
not field.remote_field.through._meta.auto_created                                                                                                                                                  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```                                                                                                   
After hit the /api/register/ getting this error.

Comment: that involve different problem i recommend you create another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the existing users from Database and deleted the previous migration files from migration folder. After again migrations issue has been resolved