# Why qlite3.OperationalError: no such column: loginsignup_customusers.password While creating CustomUser and CustomUserManager?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have just started learning Django and stuck my self in very strange condition.
I have created my own CustomUser instead of available in `django.contrib.auth.models` for authentication purpose.

I am getting some error or problems all together ,while running the program,i am trying to post all of them bellow.
*I know all of them are occurred due to some silly mistake which i am unable to figure out on my own*

***1)*** When ever i am trying to run python `manage.py make migrations` i am getting error as bellow:-

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to customusers without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

**2)** When using `python manage.py runserver` is worked fine and run a emulated server on my local computer.
*Now when i am trying to access* `admin/` *it shows me the following error***:-**

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: loginsignup_customusers.password
```

**Second after filling the signup form :-**

```
Internal Server Error: /signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\loginsignup\views.py", line 11, in signup_view
    fm.save()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\loginsignup\forms.py", line 42, in save
    user = CustomUserManager.objects.create_user(
AttributeError: type object 'CustomUserManager' has no attribute 'objects'
[11/Jun/2021 11:35:58] "POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 67683
```

**Bellow i am posting CustomUser and CustomUserManager class :-**

**CustomUser:-**

```
class CustomUsers(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

**CustomUserManager:-**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password, **other_fields):
        email = email.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have another migration file in the migration folder, which you should delete and then try to run makemigrations. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119855/error-you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-password-to-account-without)